# How to make an iOS app aware of data changes on the server without any user action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-synchronization

Suppose I have an e-commerce ios app (like snapdeal, flipkart etc.) and I want to make my app notified when there is any change in the data stored on the server.

For instance, take an example of price change of any product in any category, so how can I update the price for that product without putting it to user's knowledge, whether the user is on that particular screen (currently seeing that product for which the price is changed) or on any other screen.

is it possible to do? if YES, how can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: well you'd build a system with Parse.com, Firebase.com or PubNub.com.  You'll have to become generally expert in client-server systems.  It's fortunate that this is incredibly easier today than even just two years ago.  TBC of course, part of that system, is using **Push notifications** as MrBlackus mentions in his answer.

Comment: Why not poll the server in the background when the user starts using the app?  What's the advantage of updating while the app is in the background and the user isn't even using the app?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) to do that.

It allows your server to send data to your app, **that warns user or not** (you choose), and your app is *awake* by this push a can work on background mode.

In order to allow you app to work in background, you have to enable **Background fetch** options

From [Apple Background execution guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) :

> Apps that need to check for new content periodically can ask the system to wake them up so that they can initiate a fetch operation for that content. To support this mode, enable the Background fetch option from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the UIBackgroundModes key with the fetch value in your app’s Info.plist file.)

**Edit about BaaS**

As mentioned in comments, implementing the whole push notification system yourself can be difficult, especially if you are doing it for the first time.

That's why you can use a *BaaS* (Backend as a Service) that handle push notification for you like [Parse.com](http://parse.com), [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com) or whatever you want. It simplify **a lot**  the process, but it remains APNS on the back, so it's important to understand how it works.

Comment: The OP doesn't want the user notified; only the app.  Therefore, what's the point?

Comment: You can send a push notification without any alert

Comment: @JoeBlow Yep, you're right. Once you know you have to use APNS, you're free to choose the BaaS you want if you don't want to implement it yourself, but it's important to understand how it works if you want to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend, like Mr. Blackus said in his answer, to use Apple Push Notification service. However, I will add one bit of information -

**Don't use the service to send the actual data**, only send a small packet of information telling your application to request more data from the server.

The process should be something like this:

1. Server asks Apple service to send Push notification to your app.
2. App receives push notification (but does not show any badge to the user).
3. App interprets the data sent from the server as a "refresh data" notification.
4. Fire POST or GET request upon determining type of notification received.
5. Update your data from the request response.

Comment: @JoeBlow It goes without saying you can use 3rd party libraries to handle a lot of this process for you, but I think it's important to understand the underlying process in order for the developer to meet the requirements specifically for their need.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Polling - app asks for list of products whose prices has changed. You can setup a timer, which triggers itself after every `X` seconds.

2.) Socket connection - between app and the server. App can generate a unique token (such as identifierForVendor), and use it in the socket conenction. Server can notifiy all the apps (using this token), to notify about the changed prices.

Approach 2 is better, as it is less expensive ( in terms of networking).

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is inconceivable you would "poll" in such a situation in this day and age.  You might as well suggest writing machine code from scratch to bring up a button on iOS.